# How to compress JPGs in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: mobile, compression, titanium, jpeg, appcelerator-titanium

I need to take pictures with the device camera in Appcelerator Titanium and then compress the resulting image. It's already possible to save as .png and .jpg of any dimensions with the existing SDK, but no way I can see yet to apply compression to the .jpg (currently saves with no compression at large file sizes). Is there a way to do this in later Titanium SDKs and/or what are the best third-party modules for doing this (for both iOS and Android)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this module https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.imagefactory 
to compress image and it's work fine

```
var compressQuality = 0.8;
//compression quality 80%
blob = ImageFactory.compress(blob, compressQuality);
blob = ImageFactory.imageAsResized(blob, {
    height : outputHeight,
    width : outputWidth
});
```